# Using Kong API Gateway as a proxy for Cisco UCCX

Tags: rest, kong

I am running Cisco UCCX 11.0 which is a Contact Center server that is based on a Java scripting engine. Scripts are build using the 'Script Editor' software where you drag elements (Java Beans) to define the script logic. One of the steps in the script is to perform a REST Call. Unfortunately this step does not support adding Custom Headers such as Authorization headers and thus is limited to Basic Authentication only.

I would like the script to make a REST Call to an external API that uses a static Bearer Token. Am I correct in saying I could use Kong Gateway for this? Here is my idea of the flow:

```
UCCX Makes REST Call to Kong with Basic Authentication ---> Kong Gateway recieves the request ---> Kong Gateway makes it's request to External API with static Bearer Token ---> External API responds back to Kong ---> Kong forwards the Response back to UCCX
```

Is this type of flow possible/easy to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be managed by assigning the Request Transformer plugin to the Kong API exposing the upstream service.

Example:

Let's assume you have an API endpoint on Kong called `/myapi` that is forwarding to your upstream service.

You then assign the Request Transformer plugin to the `/myapi` API.

For your case, you will most likely want to be using the `config.add.headers` option when configuring the Request Transformer plugin to add the required header authentication which will be added to all upstream requests.

Relevant Gitter Conversation:
https://gitter.im/Mashape/kong?at=587c3a9c074f7be763d686db